# PlatformView is missing in view hierarchy

Tags: android, flutter

I'm currently developing Flutter application for RealWear HMT-1, it's an industrial Android computer that is worn on the head and all the interaction with it is built on voice commands. It runs a background service, which translates voice commands into button clicks and other gestures. Virtually every application can be controlled by voice, but in order to help the service find some control you need, you should provide some additional metadata in your view layout. It supports searching by text, resource-id and content-description attributes. Unfortunately, you can't set these attributes for Flutter widgets.

Luckily, there's a way to embed native Android views into Flutter application. I created a simple button plugin as described here https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-platformview-how-to-create-flutter-widgets-from-native-views-366e378115b6, and successfully managed to diplay this button in sample app.
But here comes the problem - this native button is invisible inside view hierarchy, I can't select it in UI Automator Viewer, and I don't see it inside views tree. Worst of all, that it's not detected by the HMT-1 speech service, which usually marks all the detected buttons (even regular Flutter buttons, those, which I can't bind metadata to) with some numeric overlay, but not this button.
Googling made me think that this might be connected to Accesibility, and perhaps I should implement some AccesibilityDelegate or AccessibilityNodeProvider, so I tried this approach, but with no luck.

I'm new to Android as well to Flutter, and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Gotcha. You have to wrap your widget with Semantics widget, and define onTap callback in case of button to make it clickable. After that, the accessibility tools will be able to detect the widget inside view hierarchy.